# Clarification on the meaning of "uniqueness" in the (linked) Matrix diagonalization theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, generalized-eigenvector

I came across [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/matrix-decompositions-1.html) source yesterday, where they say: given a square real matrix S of size $nxn$, with n linearly independent eigenvectors, there exists an eigendecomposition such as $S=UDU^{-1}$. If the eigenvalues on the diagonal of D are distinct (which I suppose it means of mulitplicity 1, correct?), **this decomposition is unique**.

I don't understand the latter sentence (this decomposition is unique). What do they mean by unique?

For example, given a square matrix, in the particular case where the matrix is symmetric, if all eigenvalues have multiplicity 1, then each eigenvector associated to a certain eigenvalue can be re-expressed as a multiplication between a scalar and the normalized eigenvector for that eigenvalue. So denoting by x the normalized eigenvector, taking $cx$, where c is a scalar, still gives an eigenvector which is linearly independent from the eigenvectors of the other eigenvalues (i.e. if the multiplicity of all eigenvalues is 1, then normalized eigenvectors are unique up to a sign transformation +/-1*x, so setting c=1 implies $1x$ is clearly unique). So in that case, the decomposition $S=UDU^{-1}$ is not unique: there may exist multiple matrixes $U$ such that $S=UDU^{-1}$ obtained by multiplying any eigenvector in the columns of $U$ by a scalar. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In that source they often talk about standardized eigenvectors, so maybe are they referring to the special case where we consider only the standardized version of the eigenvectors? As specified in the theorem below in the same page regarding symmetric square matrixes? Otherwise, what am I misinterpreting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the decomposition is not unique. And the referenced text is wrong in claiming that it is. Certainly the change of basis matrix $U$ is not unique, and its columns can be independently multiplied by nonzero scalars without changing the validity of the decomposition. The diagonal matrix has more claim to unicity, but still its entries can be permuted (if the columns of $U$ are correspondingly permuted). However the linked text take that into account be requiring the diagonal entries to be decreasing. Note that this can only be done since the text is supposing the existence of (distinct) real eigenvalues; if one wants to allow complex eigenvalues, then this method will not so easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc for the detailed explanation. Yes you’re right it is worth noticing as you said that they specify that the eigenvalues are sorted in decreasing order (so this adds some specificity to the solution). And we are talking about real ones, yes. Just a question at this point for you: could we say that the theorem would be correct if they JUST added “denoting by U the matrix whose columns are normalized eigenvectors then the decomposition is unique”?

Comment: If you give a special meaning to "normalized" so that every nonzero vector has exactly one normalized multiple then yes. For instance you can require the first nonzero entry of every column of $U$ to be equal to $1$. However, with the more common inner-product related norm, there are two normalized multiples of every nonzero vector, and you do not get uniqueness. Note that (contrary to the latter) the former normalization operation is discontinuous, and this is no accident: for topological reasons no normalization that chooses a unique vector on any line through $0$ can be continuous.

Comment: Thank you Marc, I really appreciated your help

Comment: Also because notice that without your help, blindly following the source, I would have been in serious troubles later, so I really want to thank you and, in addition to upvoting for your help, I just want to stress that I really appreciated and think that your 99k reputation is absolutely deserved. Best

Answer (score 1):

They are being very vague about the word "unique". As you have correctly explained, there always are infinitely many eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalue (as long as the underlying field is infinite).

What can be said is that there exists a unique "system of coordinates" in which the matrix is diagonal. Observe that scaling one of the eigenvectors, or reordering them, doesn't really change the underlying basis. More technically, there is only one way of decomposing the space into the direct sum of eigenspaces of $S$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leo . Yes, they have been vague, and if you notice later, when they talk about the special case of the symmetric matrix, they clarify that they are identifying the eigenvectors as the normalized ones. But it is not done for the theorem above, where eigenvectors are intended in general sense. Since theorem 1 anyway is more general than the second one, then it should include the special case of symmetry, so something is not very clear in theorem 1. Unless I am misinterpreting what they mean by “unique”

Comment: For now I leave the question as unanswered just to see if any other member maybe adds some useful thoughts on this that may complement the explanation